# python unittest skip test without super

Tags: python, nosetests

I have tried various things like raising Skip() but nothing works, everything simply fails my entire tests.

I have code similar to:

```
class ConfigPageTest(BaseTestClass):

@unittest.skipIf(isWindows, 'msg')
def test_three(self):
    pass
```

the problem is,
when i want to skip a test, i do NOT want to run it's base class's super().
i.e. my program fails because although i am skipping the test, 
i am still running the "BaseTestClass" constructor. which fails sue to the isWindows.
How can I skip the test without running the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to raise `SkipTest` exception in your `BaseTestClass` constructor, or right before your failing code, something like this:

```
from unittest.case import SkipTest

# before your current failing platform specific code
if isWindows():
    raise SkipTest("skipping this test on Windows")
```

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy.
However this solution doesn't work. i've tried it.
i don't know why, but my nose infrastructure doesnt catch any such "skip" exceptions. instead of being marked as "skipped" it crashes the entire infrastructure. that i why i need a better solution.